# RTextTools, trying to give more than one label to a document

Tags: r, text-mining

RTextTools creates a container of class matrix_container-class using the syntax:

```
    create_container(matrix, labels, trainSize=NULL, testSize=NULL, virgin)
```

Is there a way I can give 2-3 labels to a document instead of just one per document? I have a list of labels that can be inconsistent, some documents have just 1 label, others have 4 labels and it varies throughout.

Edit: This is a multi-label classification problem, is there any implementations of this in R?

Any suggestion will help!